# MySQL - Update table values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have two tables -
`subjects` and `questions`.

Structure and rows of table `subjects` are like :-

```
----------------------------
subject_id | subject_name
----------------------------
1          | physics
2          | chemistry
3          | biology
```

Structure and rows of table `questions` are like :-

```
question_id | subject_id | subject_name | question
---------------------------------------------------------
1           | 0          | physics      | demo_question_1
2           | 0          | physics      | demo_question_2
3           | 0          | chemistry    | demo_question_3
4           | 0          | biology      | demo_question_4
```

I added column `subject_id` in `questions` table after I had already inserted some rows. **I want to bulk update `subject_id` of `questions` table as per `subjects` table.** I can update them individually, using `WHERE`, but I was hoping if any single query would do this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by a single query versus a `WHERE`, but I think this will suit your needs.

```
UPDATE questions q, subjects s 
SET q.subject_id = s.subject_id 
WHERE q.subject_name = s.subject_name;
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Earlier, I meant running individual  update queries  e.g. `where subject_name='physics'` etc.

Comment: Gotcha, yes this did it all at once, glad it helped.